# delete rows based on first N columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a datafame:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-12-31','2018-02-01','2018-03-01'],'type':['Asset','Asset','Asset'],'Amount':[1,0,0],'Amount1':[1,0,0],'Ted':[1,0,0]})
df
```

I want to delete rows where the first three columns are 0. I don't want to use the name of the column as it changes. In this case, I want to delete the 2nd and 3rd rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, :3].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
#alternative solution with inverting mask by ~
#df = df[~df.iloc[:, :3].eq(0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   Amount  Amount1  Ted        date   type
0       1        1    1  2017-12-31  Asset
```

**Detail**:

First select N columns by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, :3])
   Amount  Amount1  Ted
0       1        1    1
1       0        0    0
2       0        0    0
```

Compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (`!=`):

```
print (df.iloc[:, :3].ne(0))

   Amount  Amount1    Ted
0    True     True   True
1   False    False  False
2   False    False  False
```

Get all rows at least one `True` per row by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, :3].ne(0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```